# Animaciones en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animación

me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de animar una imagen para que se mueva por la pantalla según se va arrastrando de un lado a otro.

Lo que quiero sería parecido a pintar en la pantalla con el dedo pero en vez de pintar arrastrar una imagen.

Comment: revisa este plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Comment: Ese no me sirve, lo que yo busco es poder mover una imagen pequeña por toda la pantalla, no hacer zoom en ella y desplazarme por la imagen. Igualmente muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres contenido avanzado con Draggable revisa mi video :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY5VclVPUYg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se consigue con el Widget [Dragabble](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) que proporciona Flutter.